# How can you change plots into ggplot format?

Tags: r

I have a problem changing plot in ggplot format. The data I used in plot is match.obj.
Info about match.obj

when plotting the object with this code:

```
plot(match.obj,type = "hist")
```

I received the following picture.

[image]

As I did using fortify to change data type to make it compatible for ggplot:

```
my_data <- fortify(POD_dataset) # data for ggplot use
```

it gave me an error.

> Fehler: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by
> `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class matchit.

How can you change the format so that iit is compatible for ggplot?

So I will make my question more clear with the help of my code. My question is at the end.

```
m.out1<-matchit(formula = ps.formula,data = POD_dataset,
                   distance = POD_dataset$PS,
                   method = "nearest" , replace = FALSE,
                   caliper = .1*sd(logitPS),ratio = 1)
POD_dataset$PS <- m.out1$distance
summary(m.out1$distance)
m.out1
summary(m.out1)


library("MatchIt")
matches <- as.data.frame(m.out1$match.matrix)
colnames(matches) <- c("matched_unit")
matches$matched_unit <- as.numeric(
  as.character(matches$matched_unit))
matches$treated_unit <-as.numeric(rownames(matches))
matches.only <- matches[!is.na(matches$matched_unit),]
head(matches.only)
POD_dataset[POD_dataset$id  %in% as.numeric(matches.only[2,]),]
```

I used this (below) code to create the normal plot. And I obtained the normal histogram that is shown below.

```
plot(m.out1,type = "hist")
```

But I want m.out1 plot in ggplot, My question is : How can I get the object m.out1 in ggplot. Please, can anyone help me.

Comment: Unfortunately the information you provided is not very useful.  To help us to help you could you please make your issue reproducible by sharing a sample of your **data**? ? See [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Simply type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you try to plot a `matchit` object. This object is basically a list of different items. So you need to pick the item that you want to plot.

I used an example from the documentation to illustrate how you can get the results into a data frame.

```
library(MatchIt)
data("lalonde")

# Default: 1:1 NN PS matching w/o replacement
m.out1 <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + race + nodegree +
                    married + re74 + re75, data = lalonde)
m.out1
summary(m.out1)

# Select the table you want to use for plotting and save it as a separate object.

df <- m.out1$X
```

I hope this helps . It is certainly easier if you can provide example code we can use to solve your problem.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I've edited my question above and included the code to make it clearer. Could you please kindly help me in resolving my issue?

Comment: I am afraid this code is not reproducible, i.e. I cannot run it in R without a dataset. You need to provide data and then your `ps.formula`